# Inserción de un registro con Android Studio y Web Services con PHP

Tags: mysql, android-studio, mysqli, phpmyadmin, webservice

Hola comunidad de stack overflow, hace algunos días había preguntado cómo se debía hacer la inserción de un registro por medio de web services y android studio. Amablemente me apoyaron y todo resultó muy bien. Actualización: El problema es que las variables que tengo en mi web service no se envían correctamente, para ser más especifico (matricula y nombre), ya que apellidos no tiene ningún problema, al realizarse la inserción en mi tabla me devuelve valores vacios: Un 0 para la matricula y para nombre no se ve la cadena de texto que ingrese.

> Estructura de mi tabla
> [image: Estructura de la tabla usuarios]

> Código de mi web service

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'imssqr';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

// Creas la conexion
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Checkeas la conexion
if ($con->connect_error) {
  die("Error en la conexion: " . $con->connect_error);
}

// Se prepara la insercion de datos
if(isset($_POST['matricula'])){
$matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
}
if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
}
if(isset($_POST['apellidos'])){
$apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
}


$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios(matricula, nombre, apellidos) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

try{
 $stmt->bind_param("iss", $matricula, $nombre, $apellidos);
 $stmt->execute();

//echo 'Insertado';
} catch(Exception $e){
 echo 'Excepcion: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
$stmt->close();
$con->close();
?>
```

> Método de inserción de android studio

```
    // Método para el registro de usuarios
    public void registrarUsuario(String URL) {
        StringRequest stringR = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El registro fue insertado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
                parametros.put("matricula", eTMatricula.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("nombre", eTNombre.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("apellidos", eTApellidos.getText().toString());
                return parametros;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue rQ = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        rQ.add(stringR);
    }
}
```

> Actualización: El usuario @Excorpion, me estuvo ayudando con el
> archivo config.php, pero el problemas a lo que entiendo y @Excorpion
> me comento se encuentra en el método que envía los datos atravez de
> android studio.

> Resolución:

Al final logre resolver el problema, ayudando también de un post de stack overflow, pero en la pagina en ingles, resulta ser que el problema estaba en el objeto de tipo HashMap, resulta ser que para hacer inserción se necesita en efecto un HashMap<String,String>, pero este solo acepta puros String's, y resulta ser que como tenia mi método, aunque lo hacia, resulta ser que no se debe de hacer de esa manera.

> Codigo método funcionando:

```
public void registrarUsuario(String URL) {
    // Obtenemos la información de los editText y se convierte a String
    String matricula = eTMatricula.getText().toString();
    String nombre = eTNombre.getText().toString();
    String apellidos = eTApellidos.getText().toString();
    if(matricula.isEmpty() || nombre.isEmpty() || apellidos.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No puedes dejar campos vacios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        StringRequest stringR = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El registro fue insertado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
                parametros.put("matricula", matricula);
                parametros.put("nombre", nombre);
                parametros.put("apellidos", apellidos);
                Log.d("Tag", String.valueOf(parametros));
                return parametros;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue rQ = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        rQ.add(stringR);
    }
}
```

Como se puede observar hice ".getText().toString()", justo al iniciar el método y eso resolvio el problema. Dejo una pregunta ¿Alguien que me pudiera explicar porque sucede esto?

Comment: Si no viene cargada, el problema es del archivo que envia.

Comment: Hasta donde vimos, las variables y los POST no se están cargando. Revisa esos métodos y sus envios al otro archivo.

Comment: Ya revise, mi método en android studio, y la verdad no encuentro el porque solo el "apellido", es el que se envía. El método donde se envían los datos es un string request que pasa por parámetros el método POST y la url de mi servidor local.

Comment: Lo cheque en comparación con el que me funcionó en mi proyecto de prueba y no veo cual pueda ser el error.

Comment: De hecho probé cambiando el editText del nombre, pero aún así no tuve resultados.

Comment: En Android haz un Log de los parámetros que estás enviando, puede que el problema sea que esos datos estén quedando en blanco ahí. Sería cuestión de poner: `Log.d("XYZ",parametros);` antes de esta línea: `return parametros;` y revisar el Logcat.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano, cree el log, pero no logro encontrar la línea correspondiente al log que cree, esta línea la puse después de donde defino mis variables: "public static final String TAG = Registrar_Usuarios.class.getSimpleName();", para identificar el log, y antes de "return parametros:" agregue esta línea: "Log.d(TAG, eTMatricula.getText().toString());"

Comment: @A.Cedano, ¿Hice algo incorrecto?

Comment: Tienes que revisar en la pestaña llamada `Logcat` de Android Studio, que suele estar en la parte de abajo. Ahí deberías buscar el valor de `TAG` y al lado deberías estar viendo lo que hay en matrícula, aunque es mejor hacer un log completo de `parametros` como te indiqué en mi anterior comentario, así verás el objeto completo que se estaria enviando al servidor. Esto que te digo es una depuración básica en Android Studio que deberías aprender a hacer, pues te ahorrará muchísimo tiempo en lo adelante.

Comment: A.Cedano, buen día, entonces solo para confirmar el log de todos los parámetros quedaría así: Log.d(TAG, eTMatricula); Log.d(TAG, eTNombre); Log.d(TAG, eTApellidos); para hacer la prueba.

Comment: Puedes poner esto sin más: `Log.d(TAG,parametros);` así verás todo lo que hay en el Map. No hace falta poner tres logs. Luego, revisa bien en el Logcat, pues a veces se imprime mucha información ahí. Puedes filtrar por `debug`  (para eso es la `d` al poner `Log.d`), así verás menos información y podrás encontrar más rápido lo que buscas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a hacer las pruebas correspondientes.

Comment: Ya hice las pruebas y en efecto con el Log, pude observar que solo la variable de apellidos obtiene el valor que le ingrese en el editText: "D/Tag: {apellidos=Bond, matricula=, nombre=}". ¿A que se le puede atribuir?